# Is it useful to close a MongoDB connection in NodeJS when Ctrl + C is used?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm working on a NodeJS script using MongoDB.

Without going into too much details, the script take intentionally a long time to be executed and most of the time I finish it using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

I write a bit of code to properly close the connection when I do this.

But I have no idea if it's useful or definitely useless to do it...

Here is my code:

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    console.log('Connected correctly to server');

    /* Magic happens here */

    process.on('SIGINT', function () { //Should I do this ?
        console.log('Bye');
        db.close();
        process.exit();
    })
});
```

Should I use `process.on('SIGINT', fct)` or just leave node do his job?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is. If a connection is not properly closed on the client side, the server maintains that connection until a timeout is reached. Since there is a limited number of connections, closing open connections should be tried.

It is not *much* of a problem though, unless you have *a lot* of connections or RAM is already tight on the server. The RAM might be a problem because the server allocates a stack of 1MB/connection and all cursors are kept until a connection is closed (either by timeout or explicitly) or the cursor is exhausted.

To make a long story short: Yes, it is a good idea to close connections made to the server to be resource efficient, but it is not [TEOTWAWKI](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/TEOTWAWKI#Noun) if you don't.

Since the signal handler is not much of a problem, use it.